# Possible to integrate existing Java class with Actor?

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I am on Scala 2.10.2, Akka 2.2.0 and trying to determine if it is meaningful to integrate an existing Java class with an Actor. The Java class I have in mind is the [Apache Commons FileUpload streaming API](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/streaming.html).

This is what I got working without using an Actor

```
class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet {
  override def doGet(req: HttpServletRequest, resp: HttpServletResponse) = {
    resp.getWriter().print("Hello World!")
  }

  override def doPost(req: HttpServletRequest, resp: HttpServletResponse ) = {
    if (ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(req)) {
      val upload = new ServletFileUpload()

      // Parse the request
      val iter = upload.getItemIterator(req)
      while (iter.hasNext()) {
        val item = iter.next()
        val name = item.getFieldName()
        val stream = item.openStream()
        if (item.isFormField()) {
          println("Form field " + name + " with value " + Streams.asString(stream) + " detected.")
        } else {
          println("File field " + name + " with file name " + item.getName() + " detected.")
          saveAttachment(item.getName(), stream)
        }
      }
      resp.getWriter().print("\nFile uploads success!\n")
    } else
      resp.getWriter().print("\nNo file upload found!\n")
  }

  private def saveAttachment(...) {...}
}
```

Typically an actor handles all its messages within the `receive` method but in this case the class already has predefined methods. For lack of a better term, is there a way to actorfy this? An option I considered is creating an actor for handling the upload in `doPost` since it is a blocking call handling potentially large files. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

If there's a way to "actorfy" any interface, I'd love to know about it. =) The simplest thing to do, in my opinion, is just create a value that behaves as an actor to which you can send messages, and pull the stream handling implementation into that. So, with the important bits cut out, that would look something like the following...

```
import akka.actor.ActorDSL._

class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet {

  val streamHandler = actor(new Act {
    become {
      case req: HttpServletRequest =>
        val upload = new ServletFileUpload()
        // ...
    }
  })

  override def doPost(req: HttpServletRequest, resp: HttpServletResponse) = {
    if (ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(req)) {
      streamHandler ! req
      resp.getWriter().print("\nFile uploads success!\n") // This is optimistic; we don't really know for sure
    } else {
      resp.getWriter().print("\nNo file upload found!\n")
    }
  }
}
```

This is a duct-tapey solution, of course; the actor will crap out if you send it anything other than an HttpServletRequest, and this is obviously not really reusable code. It's just intended to demonstrate the actor DSL.

Comment: Wishful thinking on my part but `actorfy` is catchy, no? :) Your suggestion is along the lines of what I am thinking also and I don't think there isn't a less duct-tapey way of doing it, ha